# am trying to make the while loop repeats again and again by the user after it finishes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in python and I am trying to make a very basic and simple guessing game , I wanted the loop to be repeated again after it had finished.... when the user type yes in the command the loop should repeat again  please help me .....in line (31):

```
import random
password =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
guess = ""
guess_limit = 3
guess_count=0
out_of_guess=False
you_lose = True

#body of the game

while guess != password and not(out_of_guess):
    if  guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input(" enter a guess : ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guess=True
     
     
if out_of_guess:
    you_lose=True
    print("you LOSE :( ")
 
    # PLAYING again
while  True :
    answer = input("do you want to play again ??\n yes or no ??  \n ")
    yes_input= "yes"
    no_input= "no"
    
    if yes_input == answer:
        random.shuffle(password)
    #here i want to return from the beginning to start playing again
    elif no_input == answer:
        break
    else:
        print("********INVALID INPUT********")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the whole program in one `while True` loop; then when you get to the play again section, you can just restart with `continue`:

```
import random
password = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

while  True :
    guess = ""
    guess_limit = 3
    guess_count=0
    out_of_guess=False
    you_lose = True

    while guess != password and not(out_of_guess):
        if  guess_count < guess_limit:
            guess = input(" enter a guess : ")
            guess_count += 1
        else:
            out_of_guess=True

    if out_of_guess:
        you_lose=True
        print("you LOSE :( ")
    answer = input("do you want to play again ??\n yes or no ??  \n ")
    yes_input= "yes"
    no_input= "no"

    if yes_input == answer:
        random.shuffle(password)
        continue
    elif no_input == answer:
        break
    else:
        print("********INVALID INPUT********")
```

But right now, **it is impossible for the password to be guessed** because the password is a `list` and `input()` is returning a `str`.  You could make a `str` version of the password to check against, though:

```
import random
password = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

while  True :
    str_password = ''.join(str(i) for i in password)
    #so correct input is "12345678910"
    guess = ""
    guess_limit = 3
    guess_count=0
    out_of_guess=False
    you_lose = True

    while guess != str_password and not(out_of_guess):
    #and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even work. You compare a `string` to a `list`. I think that you want to choose random element (number) from the list, and then check if the input is equal to that random.

I organized your code and make it look more clean.

```
import random

pass_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def game(guess: int) -> str:
    guess_count = 0
    while not guess_count <= 3:
        if guess == random.choice(pass_list):
            return 'You won!'
        guess_count += 1
    return 'You Lose'

while True:
    guess = int(input('Enter a guess: '))
    print(game(guess))
    if input('Play again? ').lower() == 'yes':
        game(guess)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your code that way, you can use a function to organize your code and it will make it easier to understand.

```
import random

def password_guessing():
    guess_count = 3
    while True:
        print("\nGuesses remaining: " + str(guess_count))
        value = int(input("Enter a guess: "))
        guess = random.choice(password)
        if value == guess:
            print("Correct guess!\n You won")
            break
        else:
            guess_count -= 1
            if guess_count >= 1:
                pass
            else:
                print("You Lose :(\n")
                ans = input("You want to play again?(y/n): ")
                if ans == 'n':
                    break
                # declaring it again since value in guess_count is 0 currently
                guess_count = 3


password = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print("Password Guessing game!")
answer = input("Enter 'yes' in order to play: ")
if answer == 'yes':
    password_guessing()
    print("*****GAME OVER*****")
else:
    print("*****GAME OVER*****")
```